# Why is this allowed? Implicit conversion from lambda acting as the missing method of an interface to the interface

Tags: java, lambda, type-conversion

Background: I am new to Java (with background in C++).

So, suppose I have a class that implements an `Iterator` interface:

```
public class C implements Iterator<concreteType>{
    // implementation
}
```

Then since `Iterable<T>` is an interface that only needs the method `Iterator<T> iterator();` defined, the following is allowed (see edit at bottom for minimal example):

```
Iterable<concreteType> coll = () -> new C<concreteType>();
```

I am quite confused about what happens around the "assignment operator".

What is on the right to me is an (using C++ language) function object. And assigning a function object to `Iterable` doesn't seem to make sense. Isn't operator overloading forbidden in Java?

The second possibility is that the lambda is run, return an `C`, and is in turn assigned to `Iterable`. Is an implicit type conversion going on here (`C` to `Iterable`) or is an `Iterable` temporarily constructed from the type `C` variable returned from lambda and then the temporary is assigned to `coll`? [This doesn't seem to be the case, as the example at the bottom when run doesn't print as required if ctor is actually called.]

The third possibility is that the lambda provides the missing method that's necessary and sufficient to implement an `Iterable` interface, a temporary `Iterable` is constructed simply by the lambda and then assigned to the left. In this scenario, is there really a temporary being constructed (so later recycled) or no temporary is involved but type conversion (lambda to `Iterable`) is automatically done?

Thank you.

## Edit#:

In addressing the down vote, here's a compilable minimal example:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class C implements Iterator<Integer>{

    private Integer nextInt;
    private Integer i;

    public C() // to test if the constructor is actually called
    {
        System.out.println("C ctor");
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return nextInt != null;
    }

    public Integer next()
    {
       return nextInt;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Iterable<Integer> coll = () -> new C();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's allowed.  (It's not considered particularly good practice, because `Iterable` isn't annotated `@FunctionalInterface`, meaning it's not *intended* to be used this way.)

> And assigning a function object to Iterable doesn't seem to make sense.

Why?  An `Iterable` really is, at its base, a supplier of iterators.  What you get is equivalent to

```
new Iterable<ConcreteType>() {
  @Override public Iterator<ConcreteType> iterator() {
    return new C<ConcreteType>();
  }
}
```

I have a hard time figuring out what you're saying, but what's actually happening seems closest to the third possibility you mentioned.  You're creating a new `Iterable` that, when asked for an iterator, creates a `new C<ConcreteType>()` and returns it.

Comment: The reason why "assigning a function object to an iterable doesn't make sense to me" is that these two types are really meant for different things: one is providing access to something, and the other is providing an action. And even thought the "action" could in principle be "providing access", it is really strange.